# Different result for x and y limits in 2 different code cells of Google Colab

Tags: python, matplotlib, google-colaboratory

Have a look at the code in the following image:

[image]

Question:

Since I am not resetting the `plt` variable, how did I get different limits of X and Y dimensions in the 2 different code cells of Google Colab?

Comment: I'm not experienced with google colab. But it looks like it runs `plt.show()` in the background if the figure is "defined". And `plt.show()` resets the figure. I've tried your code in the console and it always prints `(-1.0, 3.5)` with `print(plt.xlim())` until I run `plt.show()`. After that it prints `(0.0, 1.0)`.

Answer (score 1):

1. `matplotlib.pyplot` is not a variable, it's a module, that encloses functions from inside matplotlib for ease of use.
2. the behavior depends on the backend used by matplotlib, when running in an ipy notebook, matplotlib uses an inline backend.
3. the inline backend automatically calls `plt.show()` on every code block, thus releasing the last figure, and a new figure is created in each code block.